# Ubuntu 22.04 shutdown freeze

Tags: 22.04, shutdown, freeze

A fey days ago, I found a problem with my laptop. When I tried to shutdown my laptop, the shutdown screen appears. A few seconds later, this screen is frozen and nothing happens.

I tried to shutdown the laptop and wait for around an hour, but unfortunately this problem is still here.
I also tried the swap off solution, but here again it failed to resolve the problem.
I tried a clean os reinstall by removing ubuntu with the problem not fixed.

I run ubuntu on an Acer Nitro AN515-57. The logs below are from a fresh ubuntu install.

- With the command `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e`, I found this line multiple times :

```
august 14 09:31:24 user gnome-shell[1707]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.
august 14 09:31:24 user gnome-shell[1707]: == Stack trace for context 0x55ac7e4d9490 ==
august 14 09:31:24 user gnome-shell[1707]: The offending signal was notify on NMDeviceEthernet 0x55ac80430330.
august 14 09:31:24 user gnome-shell[1707]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.
august 14 09:31:24 user gnome-shell[1707]: The offending signal was notify on NMDeviceWifi 0x55ac804343b0.
august 14 09:31:24 user gnome-shell[1707]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.
august 14 09:31:24 user gnome-shell[1707]: The offending signal was notify on NMActiveConnection 0x55ac8043c180.
august 14 09:31:24 user gnome-shell[1707]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.
august 14 09:31:24 user gnome-shell[1707]: The offending signal was state-changed on NMDeviceEthernet 0x55ac80430330.
august 14 09:31:24 user gnome-shell[1707]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.
august 14 09:31:24 user gnome-shell[1707]: The offending signal was state-changed on NMDeviceWifi 0x55ac804343b0.
august 14 09:31:24 user gnome-shell[1707]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.
august 14 09:31:24 user gnome-shell[1707]: The offending signal was destroy on Gjs_ui_appDisplay_FolderGrid 0x55ac7ec25b80.
august 14 09:31:24 user gnome-shell[1707]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.
august 14 09:31:24 user gnome-shell[1707]: The offending signal was destroy on Gjs_ui_appDisplay_FolderGrid 0x55ac7ec25b80.
august 14 09:31:24 user gnome-shell[1707]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.
august 14 09:31:24 user gnome-shell[1707]: The offending signal was destroy on Gjs_ui_appDisplay_FolderGrid 0x55ac7ec25b80.
```

- I found also this in the kernel log :

```
Aug 15 10:20:26 user kernel: [    1.299204] ACPI Error: Field [AFU0] Base+Offset+Width 512+0+1 is beyond end of region [COMP] (length 512) (20221020/exfldio-163)
Aug 15 10:20:26 user kernel: [    1.299222] 
Aug 15 10:20:26 user kernel: [    1.299223] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_STA]
Aug 15 10:20:26 user kernel: [    1.299223] 
Aug 15 10:20:26 user kernel: [    1.299224] No Arguments are initialized for method [_STA]
Aug 15 10:20:26 user kernel: [    1.299224] 
Aug 15 10:20:26 user kernel: [    1.299225] ACPI Error: Aborting method \AFUB._STA due to previous error (AE_AML_REGION_LIMIT) (20221020/psparse-529)
```

Do you have any ideas of what coud be the cause of the problem? If yes, can you help me resolve this problem?

I thank anyone willing to help me in advance.

Edit : I found the answer to my problem. I updated the ubuntu os version to the last 23.04.

Comment: The former log could be your freezing issue though, I've gotten same kind of spam - often slightly different messages but this time exactly the same, as I came here by a google search - usually the bug is triggered when switching windows with shortcut keys! Then gnome-shell can produce gigabytes of logs in minutes, and that alone clogs the system completely (Even journald was consuming 100 % of cpu!)

Comment: I thank you for you answer. But, I found the solution : I updated my operating system to the last 23.04.